# Perl: How to use variables from one script in another script?

Tags: perl, active-directory

I have a script that connects to active directory and then grabs a bunch of attributes and stores them in variables.  I would like to use this for many different scripts that I'm using and would rather not have to add this code to each script.  If I want to just print out the data that seems to work just fine using `require 'script.pl';`.  However if I want to reuse the variables from that script, that doesn't work.  So in the main script I have variables like $givenname, $sn, $telephonenumber, $manager etc and I would like to use those same variables in other scripts.

Comment: Read up on modules and packages etc. After that, you may want to read the `Exporter` documentation

Answer (score 2):

Do not store values in variables. Instead write a subroutine that [return](http://p3rl.org/return)s the values to the caller.